# SQL to return one resultset from multiple tables when either table could return zero results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with some columns that are similar and some that are different. I need to return a result that merges the differing columns into one result set, however, I need a condition that may result in either of the tables having no matches, I tried a union, but that is returning two rows with null values, and I would like just one. Here are two example tables:

```
TableA
----------------------------------------------------
| ID | ColumnA | ColumnB | ForeignKeyA | TimeStamp |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Val1    | Val2    | KeyA        | 2013-01-01|
----------------------------------------------------
| 2  | Val3    | Val4    | KeyB        | 2013-01-02|
----------------------------------------------------

TableB
------------------------------------------
| ID | ColumnC | ForeignKeyA | TimeStamp |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | Val5    | KeyA        | 2013-01-01|
------------------------------------------
| 2  | Val6    | KeyC        | 2013-01-02|
------------------------------------------
```

and here are some pseudo queries and the return values I would like:

1)

```
SELECT TableA.ColumnA AS ColumnA, 
TableA.ColumnB AS Column B, 
TableB.ColumnC  AS ColumnC,
TableA.id AS TableA_ID,
TableB.id AS TableB_ID
(WHERE ForeignKeyA in either table = KeyA and TimeStamp in either table = 2013-01-01)

>>
-------------------------------------------------------
| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | TableA_ID | TableB_ID |
-------------------------------------------------------
| Val1    | Val2    | Val5    | 1         | 1         |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

2)

```
SELECT TableA.ColumnA AS ColumnA, 
TableA.ColumnB AS Column B, 
TableB.ColumnC  AS ColumnC,
TableA.id AS TableA_ID,
TableB.id AS TableB_ID
(WHERE ForeignKeyA in either table = KeyB and TimeStamp in either table = 2013-01-02)

>>
 -------------------------------------------------------
| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | TableA_ID | TableB_ID |
-------------------------------------------------------
| Val3    | Val4    | Null    | 2         | Null      |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

3)

```
SELECT TableA.ColumnA AS ColumnA, 
TableA.ColumnB AS Column B, 
TableB.ColumnC  AS ColumnC,
TableA.id AS TableA_ID,
TableB.id AS TableB_ID
(WHERE ForeignKeyA in either table = KeyC and TimeStamp in either table = 2013-01-02)

>>
 -------------------------------------------------------
| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | TableA_ID | TableB_ID |
-------------------------------------------------------
| Null    | Null    | Val6    | Null      | 2         |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You are missing the 'From' clause in your psuedo queires and the solution you are looking for will be found in your join statements.  I beleive what you want here is a full outer join

Comment: I left out the FROM because I wasn't sure what table should actually be specified. I am currently trying a full outer join query, I haven't gotten it working, but from your comment it sounds like I may be on the right track.

Comment: you are close then.  An inner join returns only rows in both tables, left join would return all rows in the 'left' table (the first one in the join clause) with nulls returned from the second table where the record isn't found.  Right join is the opposite of that, full outer join returns all rows in both tables with nulls returned for records found in one table but not ther other.  Post up the from statement if you are having issues there and we'll help you organize the tables as you need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your query you can use `full outer join` like this (you can add columns into `on` clause, but it'll not change anything):

```
with
cteA as (select * from TableA where TimeStamp = _ts and ForeignKeyA = _fk),
cteB as (select * from TableB where TimeStamp = _ts and ForeignKeyA = _fk)
select
    A.ColumnA, A.ColumnB, B.ColumnC,
    A.ID as TableA_ID, B.ID as TableB_ID
from cteA as A
    full outer join cteB as B on 1 = 1
```

But you can use `full outer join` without prefiltering (This would be less efficient is you have indexes on `ForeignKeyA` and `TimeStamp` columns):

```
select
    A.ColumnA, A.ColumnB, B.ColumnC,
    A.ID as TableA_ID, B.ID as TableB_ID
from TableA as A
    full outer join TableB as B
        on B.ForeignKeyA = A.ForeignKeyA and B.TimeStamp = A.TimeStamp
where
    coalesce(A.ForeignKeyA, B.ForeignKeyA) = _fk and
    coalesce(A.TimeStamp, B.TimeStamp) = _ts
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ed966/1)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

The possibly tricky detail here is to join on `(ForeignKeyA, TimeStamp)`, not on `ID` as one would normally do.

With this simplified setup (using legal column names):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_a (id int, col_a text, col_b text, fk_a text, ts timestamp);
INSERT INTO tbl_a VALUES
  (1, 'Val1', 'Val2', 'KeyA', '2013-01-01')
 ,(2, 'Val3', 'Val4', 'KeyB', '2013-01-02');

CREATE TABLE tbl_b (id int, col_c text,  fk_a text, ts timestamp);
INSERT INTO tbl_b VALUES
  (1, 'Val5', 'KeyA', '2013-01-01')
 ,(2, 'Val6', 'KeyC', '2013-01-02');
```

The **query** would be:

```
SELECT a.col_a, a.col_b, b.col_c
      ,a.id AS a_id, b.id AS b_id
FROM   tbl_a a
FULL   JOIN tbl_b b USING (fk_a, ts)
WHERE  'KeyA' IN (a.fk_a, b.fk_a)
AND    '2013-01-01' IN (a.ts, b.ts);
```

Should be considerably faster than using CTEs. Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

[-> SQLfiddle demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0fb66/3)